# Url correct but the dictionary is null

Tags: ios, json

I have to download data using JSON, the url is correct (tested on chrome) but I get an empty dictionary. Where did I go wrong?

```
  NSLog(@"'url is %@", stringUrl); //correct
  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringUrl]];
  NSHTTPURLResponse __autoreleasing *response = nil;
  NSError __autoreleasing *error = nil;
  NSData *result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
  // the result is:
  /* <280d0a0d 0a0d0a0d 0a0d0a0d 0a0d0a7b 22636f6d 6d6f6e22 3a7b2261 636b223a 
     224f4b22 2c226661 756c7443 6f646522 3a6e756c 6c2c2266 61756c74 53747269 
     6e67223a 6e756c6c 7d2c2274 6f74616c 223a3138 362c2270 61676522 3a312c22 
      .......*/
  NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSLog(@"  STRING IS %@", str);
  //the string is correct
 SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
 NSLog (@"The parser is %@", parser);
 //The parser is  <SBJsonParser: 0x8877400>
 NSDictionary *object = [parser objectWithData: result];

 NSLog(@" The dictionary is %@", object);// The dictionary is null
```

The result of string:

```
  NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSLog(@" THE STRING IS %@", str);

  /* ({"common":
{"ack":"OK",
 "faultCode":null,
  "faultString":null},
       "total":8,
        "page":1,
        "limit":15,
         "products":[{"name":"BANANE SOLIDAL BIOLOGICAL  - cartone/estero/2^ 
         cat.",
         "code":"52436",
         "anabel":"264342000",
         "hasPezzature":true,
         "pezzatureList": 
          [{"weight":700.000,"unit":"Gr","formatted":"700GR"}],  
            "disponible":true,
             "promotionImage":null},
         {"name":"KIWI  IT 105-120 II^ VAS
          500GR",
          "code":"52094",
          "anabel":"393261000",
           "hasPezzature":true,
           "pezzatureList":
           [{"weight":500.000,"unit":"GR","formatted":"500GR"}],
              "disponible":true,
              "promotionImage":null},
               ........
               .........]});*/
```

I put the formatting so to be readable, in fact the returned data is all on one line

Comment: What is about `result` = ? raw data that you receiving ?

Comment: have you tried to check if NSError is not nil?

Comment: Are you sure that it is returning correctly? try doing `NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; NSLog(@"%@", str);` and see what is printed. This should be you data converted to string format.

Comment: First check that you have received response or not...

Then only your dictionary will have contents... Check what is delegate method getting
fired when you receive response of your request and fill this dictionary there...

Comment: Why don't you use [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class?

Comment: @bhuXan I do believe that `sendSynchronousRequest` doesn't call any delegate methods. It is `sendAsynchronousRequest` that will call the delegate methods when you set `setDelegate:`. So just from this code even if `sendSynchronousRequest` called the delegate methods they will never get called in this code.

Comment: because before your request is completed you get result and convert it in dictionary. your dictionary is null as well as your result is also null. write this dictionary in any completion block of url request

Comment: @Popeye the string that you suggest me, return a correct result,   but do not put it later in the dictionary

Comment: @MidhunMP the **NSJSONSerialization** return me: Error parsing JSON: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x7621080 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set

Comment: Then obviously your json is invalid. Can you post an example of the string you get back?

Comment: @ConicaDegenere I am sorry I don't understand what you mean. Did you try and convert the returning data to a string and print it out. Was there a response if so please could you add it to your question so we can see the format of your so called JSON as this could be in the wrong format. Which after your comments to `midhunMP` I suspect it is in the wrong format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a "(" and ")" at the starting and ending of the JSON response when you try to cast it in a NSDictionary or NSArray, it doesnt recognize it and hence goes empty. So to get it parsed you'll need to add this:

```
str = [[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
```

before

```
SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSLog (@"The parser is %@", parser);
//The parser is  <SBJsonParser: 0x8877400>
NSDictionary *object = [parser objectWithData: result];

NSLog(@" The dictionary is %@", object);// The dictionary is null
```

Comment: Could you explain in your answer how this would solve the users in issue and what they were doing wrong. Answers that don't explain themselves and just say "Do this" doesn't help anyone.

Comment: There is a "(" and ")" at the starting and ending of the JSON response when you try to cast it in a NSDictionary or NSArray, it doesnt recognize it and hence goes empty. got it @Popeye?

Comment: I know exactly why your doing it but others might not and because of that they would need an explanation for why your doing it. So I was going for could you edit your answer to include this.